# Change Android Language without accessing all view or button IDs

Tags: android

I have the below code that is able to change language for the activity, However the drwback is that i have to know all IDs of the my views and buttons in order to change the language. What i want is to automatically load the who new set of strings based on selected not one by one as below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView messageView;
    Resources resources;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        //builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.fire));
        builder.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.language));
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setItems(R.array.languages,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Context context=getApplicationContext();
                String[] languages_array = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.languages);
                Log.d("alert", "the index is: " + languages_array[which]);
                String msg="";
                if (languages_array[which].equals("Chichewa"))msg="ny";
                else msg="en";
                messageView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                context = LocaleHelper.setLocale(MainActivity.this, msg);
                resources = context.getResources();
                messageView.setText(resources.getString(R.string.language));

            }});
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    }

}
```

I have tried below code but it is not working at all

```
                Configuration overrideConfiguration = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
                overrideConfiguration.setLocale(new Locale(msg));
                Context context2  = createConfigurationContext(overrideConfiguration);
                Resources resources = context2.getResources();
                DisplayMetrics dm = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
                resources.updateConfiguration(overrideConfiguration,dm);
```

Comment: Checkout this tutorial https://medium.com/ironsource-tech-blog/conversion-by-translation-changing-your-android-app-language-at-runtime-5c9daebf9771 to change language runtime

Answer (score 0):

To change the language in one fellswoop requires the `Activity` to be restarted.

```
    Configuration overrideConfiguration = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
    overrideConfiguration.setLocale(new Locale(msg));
    Context context2 = createConfigurationContext(overrideConfiguration);
    Resources resources = context2.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
    resources.updateConfiguration(overrideConfiguration, dm);
    //Here
    recreate()
```